# Java sale Run from main method instead as a java beans

Tags: java

[image: This is how it should look when I enter the information, and after I click on "Calc" button, I should get the Results of the calculation and show it in msgLbl![][1]]if I want to run sale at main method or as an application instead as java beans,what should I add at the main method???, because right now running it as a java beans works fine, but when I run it as an application, nothing happens because I need to add some code in main method.

```
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.awt.event.WindowListener;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Label;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Button;

import java.awt.TextField;

public class Sale extends Frame implements ActionListener, WindowListener {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Label custNameLbl = null;
    private Label itemNameLbl = null;
    private Label qtyLbl = null;
    private Label priceLbl = null;
    private Label msgLbl = null;
    private Button button = null;
    private TextField custNameTF = null;
    private TextField itemNameTF = null;
    private TextField qtyTF = null;
    private TextField priceTF = null;

    @Override
    public void windowOpened(WindowEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void windowIconified(WindowEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void windowDeiconified(WindowEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void windowActivated(WindowEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void windowDeactivated(WindowEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        int qty;
        double price;
        double cost;
        qty = Integer.parseInt(qtyTF.getText());
        price = Double.parseDouble(priceTF.getText());
        cost = price * qty * 1.065;
        this.add(msgLbl, null);
        msgLbl.setText("The cost of this " + "transaction is: $" + cost);
        custNameTF.setText("");
        itemNameTF.setText("");
        qtyTF.setText("");
        priceTF.setText("");

        // System.out.println(cost);

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    /**
     * This method initializes button
     * 
     * @return java.awt.Button
     */
    private Button getButton() {
        if (button == null) {
            button = new Button();
            button.setLocation(new Point(126, 198));
            button.setLabel("Calc");
            button.setSize(new Dimension(40, 23));
            button.addActionListener(this);
        }
        return button;
    }

    /**
     * This method initializes custNameTF
     * 
     * @return java.awt.TextField
     */
    private TextField getCustNameTF() {
        if (custNameTF == null) {
            custNameTF = new TextField();
            custNameTF.setBounds(new Rectangle(116, 42, 140, 23));
        }
        return custNameTF;
    }

    /**
     * This method initializes itemNameTF
     * 
     * @return java.awt.TextField
     */
    private TextField getItemNameTF() {
        if (itemNameTF == null) {
            itemNameTF = new TextField();
            itemNameTF.setBounds(new Rectangle(116, 77, 137, 23));
        }
        return itemNameTF;
    }

    /**
     * This method initializes qtyTF
     * 
     * @return java.awt.TextField
     */
    private TextField getQtyTF() {
        if (qtyTF == null) {
            qtyTF = new TextField();
            qtyTF.setBounds(new Rectangle(95, 114, 56, 23));
        }
        return qtyTF;
    }

    /**
     * This method initializes priceTF
     * 
     * @return java.awt.TextField
     */
    private TextField getPriceTF() {
        if (priceTF == null) {
            priceTF = new TextField();
            priceTF.setBounds(new Rectangle(203, 114, 49, 23));
        }
        return priceTF;
    }

    /**
     * I need to run sale from main method or in other words pass the values to
     * msgLbl
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Sale saleTest = new Sale();

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    /**
     * This is the default constructor
     */
    public Sale() {
        super();
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * This method initializes this
     * 
     * @return void
     */
    private void initialize() {
        msgLbl = new Label();
        msgLbl.setText("Label");
        msgLbl.setSize(new Dimension(290, 23));
        msgLbl.setAlignment(Label.CENTER);
        msgLbl.setLocation(new Point(4, 170));
        priceLbl = new Label();
        priceLbl.setBounds(new Rectangle(161, 114, 36, 23));
        priceLbl.setAlignment(Label.RIGHT);
        priceLbl.setText("Price");
        qtyLbl = new Label();
        qtyLbl.setBounds(new Rectangle(35, 114, 51, 23));
        qtyLbl.setAlignment(Label.RIGHT);
        qtyLbl.setText("Quantity");
        itemNameLbl = new Label();
        itemNameLbl.setBounds(new Rectangle(34, 77, 72, 23));
        itemNameLbl.setAlignment(Label.RIGHT);
        itemNameLbl.setText("Item Name");
        custNameLbl = new Label();
        custNameLbl.setBounds(new Rectangle(5, 42, 101, 23));
        custNameLbl.setAlignment(Label.RIGHT);
        custNameLbl.setText("Customer Name");
        this.setLayout(null);
        this.setSize(300, 229);
        this.setTitle("Frame");

        this.add(custNameLbl, null);
        this.add(itemNameLbl, null);
        this.add(qtyLbl, null);
        this.add(priceLbl, null);

        this.add(getButton(), null);
        this.add(getCustNameTF(), null);
        this.add(getItemNameTF(), null);
        this.add(getQtyTF(), null);
        this.add(getPriceTF(), null);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need a `Sale` constructor, adding all the components. something like this, though you may want to fix the formatting with LayoutManagers.

```
public Sale {
    add(custNameLbl);
    add(itemNameLbl);
    add(qtyLbl);
    ...
    // add the rest of your components
}
```

Here's how to run it.

```
public class Sale extends Frame implements ActionListener, WindowListener {

    public Sale {
       add(custNameLbl);
       add(itemNameLbl);
       add(qtyLbl);
       ...
       // add the rest of your components
    }

    ...
    // rest of code
    ...

    public static void main(String[] args){
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                Sale sale = new Sale();
                sale.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

There's actually some other things you need to fix in your code before it will run the way you want. But to get it up and running, just remember you need to add the components, before instantiating the `Frame` in the `main`.

Another hint: you seem to have you `Frame` implementing ActionListener, but what I think you really want is for the `ActionListener to be registered with your button and not the frame. Consider the following

```
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        int qty;
        double price;
        double cost;
        qty = Integer.parseInt(qtyTF.getText());
        price = Double.parseDouble(priceTF.getText());
        cost = price * qty * 1.065;
        this.add(msgLbl, null);
        msgLbl.setText("The cost of this " + "transaction is: $" + cost);
        custNameTF.setText("");
        itemNameTF.setText("");
        qtyTF.setText("");
        priceTF.setText("");

        // System.out.println(cost);

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
});
```